# Get specific value from a HTML output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the following result from a data source.

```
"<span class=\"highlight\">DSDT10</span><div>011XBY</div>"
```

The value in span and div could vary.

And I want only the value inside the span "DSDT10" in a separate variable.

**What I have tried:**

```js
var data = '<span class=\"highlight\">DSDT10</span><div>011XBY</div>';

var formattedData = data.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/g, "");

$('#output').append(formattedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

**Expectation:**

Retrieve only "DSDT10" from the data variable.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're replacing the `<span>` before `DSDT10`, but you're not replacing `</span><div>011XBY</div>` after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want to get the text within the span? You could modify your regex a bit and use a match..

```
var data = '<span class=\"highlight\">DSDT10</span><div>011XBY</div>';
var formattedData = data.match(/<span[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/span>/, "")[1];
```

But since you're using jquery you could also just do this:

```
var formattedData = $("<div>", {html: data}).find("span").text()
```

Comment: I think it needs to be `$("<div>", {html: data}).find("span").text()`. `find` won't match a top-level element.

Comment: The `.match` method shouldn't use the `g` flag, and needs `[1]` to get the capture group.

Comment: you're right, i jumped the gun. i would recommend using jquery rather than regex for this though, Vimalan.

Comment: @smerny, sure. Thanks for your help. Let me try this solution at my end.

Answer (score 1):

Only two lines of code:

```
_str = "<span class=\"highlight\">DSDT10</span><div>011XBY</div>";
_span = $(_str).filter('span').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's enough only one line:

```
$('#output').html($('span').html());
```

Comment: `$('span')` searches the DOM, he's searching a string.